# C# LINQ to XML returned results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to create a simple login in page for an WPF app. I am using the following XML file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<users>`
  `<user>`
    `<username>test1</username>`
    `<password>1test</password>`
 `</user>`
`</users>`

I am new to LINQ and don't really understand how to get anything out or assign the results to a variable.

Right now I have:

```
        XDocument users = new XDocument("users.xml");

        var queryResults =
            from u in users.Root.Descendants("user")
            where u.Element("username").Value == tbUserName.Text && u.Element("password").Value == pbPassword.Password
            select u;

        foreach (var item in queryResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

So if my query is right it will write the username and password to the console, if the login values exist in the xml file.  This is as much as I understand. I don't know what to do next to verify or validate the user login. Any help or ideas would be great.

Comment: you should check out LinqPad, it lets you run these kinds of queries on the fly. its neat. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `queryResults` is not empty, then the username and password are correct, so you can do it like this:

```
if (queryResults.Any())
{
    // log user in, let him continue
}
else
{
    // user name or password is incorrect, let the user know and possibly try again
}
```

Comment: It works when I test the query in a console application. For some reason in the WPF program I get: Non white space characters cannot be added to content. I don't know what that means.

Comment: @user, that probably means that your XAML is malformed, try checking that.

Comment: The problem was:
`XDocument users = new XDocument("users.xml");`

It should be:
`XDocument users = XDocument.Load("users.xml");` I was instantiating a new blank XML file instead of loading the XML file. Hence the white space. Thank you very much for your help!